# How to add a page inside some levels using Zend_Navigation?

Tags: arrays, zend-framework, zend-navigation

I'm using a XML ([click here to see](http://gist.github.com/570591)) with **Zend_Navigation** to render this:
[image]

which `Menu Principal` is the first level, then `Home` and `Quem Somos`, then the dropdown is the third and last level. I want this last list to be dynamic (querying from the database).

I found out that I can use the method `addPages($array)` in order to dynamically render the navigation. So I thought of querying the database for the page titles then pushing them out as arrays then use `addPages()` method. I just don't know how to add pages from an existing level of the navigation.

I know how to retrieve the array I want to add, but how do I add it as `Quem Somos`'s list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get any container by using magic methods `findOneBy*()`, eg.

```
$submenu = $container->findOneByLabel('Quem Somos');
$submenu->setPages($yourNewContainer);
```

Zend Navigation implements `RecursiveIterator` interface, so you may use `RecursiveIteratorIterator` to iterate and find anything you want manually.